# I want the same UITableView style across various table views - how can i do this?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uitableview, customization

So for example, I have a settings menu, which leads into other menus, and all have the same style to them. The table view cell cusomisation is done like this:

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell *)[self dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault
                                      reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

        cell.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        cell.textLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    }

    BOOL isFirstRowInSection = NO;

    if (indexPath.row == 0) isFirstRowInSection = YES;

    BOOL isLastRowInSection = NO;

    int numberOfRowsInSection = [tableView.dataSource tableView:self numberOfRowsInSection:indexPath.section];

    if (indexPath.section == 0 && indexPath.row == numberOfRowsInSection - 1) {
        isLastRowInSection = YES;
    }

    UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:cell.bounds];
    imageView.image = cellBackgroundImage(cell.bounds.size, isFirstRowInSection, isLastRowInSection);

    cell.backgroundView = imageView;

    //cell.textLabel.text = @"This is a cell";

    return cell;
}
```

I want this class to be used by the main settings menu and all sub-menus, but while I want them to supply their own data like what each cell's text is, i want it to take the cell styling methods from here.

How can i achieve this? Current thoughts are to replicate parts of the datasource protocol into my own delegate that they can respond to.

Answer (score 1):

You might create a specific subclass of UITableViewCell and implement your visual characteristics in the cell itself.

If you create a subclass and a nib file in InterfaceBuilder you can have a class method that looks something like

```
+ (NSString *)cellIdentifier {
    return NSStringFromClass([self class]);
}


+ (id)cellForTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    NSString *cellID = [self cellIdentifier];
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellID];
    if (cell == nil) {
        NSArray *nibObjects = [[self nib] instantiateWithOwner:nil options:nil];
        NSAssert2(([nibObjects count] > 0) && 
                  [[nibObjects objectAtIndex:0] isKindOfClass:[self class]],
                  @"Nib '%@' does not appear to contain a valid %@", 
                  [self nibName], NSStringFromClass([self class]));
        cell = [nibObjects objectAtIndex:0];
    }
    return cell;    
}
```

So, if you have defined a class (say MyTableViewCell) and Build the Interface in IB, you make sure that you make the FileOwner be an object of your MyTableViewCell and have IBOutlets of the various subclass specific visual objects and Bob's your uncle.

Then in your tableViewController's cellForRowAtIndexPath method you use something like

```
MyTableViewCell *cell = [MyTableViewCell cellForTableView:tableView];
```

This way the bulk of the visual presentation logic is maintained in the Interface Builder code.  If you are making a universal app you would have to create two nib files but that's not too difficult.

Answer (score 0):

One way you could implement this is by having your "other menus" – the ones that this tableview "leads into" – call this tableview's `- tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method.  That would look something like this:

ChildTableViewController.m:

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    // Somehow, you'll need to give this child VC a pointer to the
    // "root" tableview – I'll pretend that pointer is "rootTableView"
    return [rootTableView tableView:tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
}
```

You'll have to make sure you're being intelligent about what contents you return from that method, since now not only one tableview but many are using the method to get their cells.  You could do this by checking what `UITableView` is asking for a cell:

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell *)[self dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault
                                      reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

        cell.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        cell.textLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    }

    BOOL isFirstRowInSection = NO;

    if (indexPath.row == 0) isFirstRowInSection = YES;

    BOOL isLastRowInSection = NO;

    int numberOfRowsInSection = [tableView.dataSource tableView:self numberOfRowsInSection:indexPath.section];

    if (indexPath.section == 0 && indexPath.row == numberOfRowsInSection - 1) {
        isLastRowInSection = YES;
    }

    UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:cell.bounds];
    imageView.image = cellBackgroundImage(cell.bounds.size, isFirstRowInSection, isLastRowInSection);

    cell.backgroundView = imageView;

    //cell.textLabel.text = @"This is a cell";

    // Now, all your cells have the same formatting; do your custom 
    // data grabbing or whatever you need to do for the different
    // tableviews
    if (tableview == [self view]) {
        return cell;
    } else if (tableview = [self childTableView1]) {
        // Do the setup you'd want for your first child tableview
        return cell;
    } else if (tableview = [self childTableView2]) {
        // Do the setup you'd want for your second child tableview
        return cell;
    }   // More if statements as needed

    return cell;
}
```

It might be cleaner, though, to simply copy and paste the code from the method you showed into the `- tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method of each of your "child" tableviews.  It's not too long, and would be much less of a headache to set up.

Comment: Thanks. Copy and pasting code is never a good idea though. Say I change it in one place, then unless i remember to copy and paste it into all those other places, i have a mess on my hands.

Comment: Completely true.  Let me know if the first solution, then, works better.  You could also implement a category on UITableViewCell that spits out a pre-formatted cell when you call something like, `[UITableViewCell formattedCell]`, if you plan to use such cells often.